# Display object in data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

On my `Index.cshtml` page I have a table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th></th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
      <tr>
        <td>Test</td>
        <td>Subject</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td><a href="#" data-personnel-id="@item.ID" data-personnel="@item" class="js-personnel-detail">Details</a></td>
      </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My goal is to assign the `item` object to a data-attribute so that I don't have specify each different object property in it's own data attribute.

When I try this I get this when I Inspect the element:

```
data-personnel="System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Person_EA5AC055D1501E594DFBC8C0E360599F673410050ABB4A55BB0B191F6E442210"
```

but `data-personnel-id="7"`... so I can assign individual properties but not the entire object.

Can this be done?

Comment: You are trying to poke a .NET object (bits in memory) into a text document that will be sent halfway around the globe.  What would you expect to be in `data-personnel`??   When I've needed to do this I usually serialize the object to json and poke the json text in there.

Comment: In javascript try: JSON.stringify 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Try this:  data-personnel-id="@Model[item].ID"   It looks like the foreach is being handled like a JS foreach where the item is actually just the name of the property, not the value.

Comment: @SamAxe can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JSON.NET...

```
<div data-object='@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item)'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data-personnel-id="@Model[item].ID"
```

It looks like the foreach is being handled like a JS foreach where the item is actually just the name of the property, not the value.

Comment: I'm not talking about the `id` data attribute.. the other attribute

Comment: Same pattern.  data-personnel="@Model[item]"